# cannot redefine component. ID: org.scala-sbt-compiler-bridge_2.12-1.3.5-bin_2.12.11__52.0

Tags: scala, sbt

I use sbt version 1.3.10 and get the following error for "sbt publish". openjdk-8.0.171.
What should I do? Did somebody met this problem?

```
[info] Non-compiled module 'compiler-bridge_2.12' for Scala 2.12.10. Compiling...
[info]   Compilation completed in 7.245s.
[info] Attempting to fetch org.scala-sbt:compiler-bridge_2.12:1.3.5.
[error] ## Exception when compiling 1 sources to /my/user/folder/scala-seed-project/project/target/scala-2.12/sbt-1.0/classes
[error] cannot redefine component.  ID: org.scala-sbt-compiler-bridge_2.12-1.3.5-bin_2.12.10__52.0, files: /tmp/sbt_c2c7213/org.scala-sbt-compiler-bridge_2.12-1.3.5-bin_2.12.10__52.0.jar
```

I try to publish sbt example. My buils.sbt file is:

```
import Dependencies._

ThisBuild / scalaVersion     := "2.12.8"
ThisBuild / version          := "0.1.2-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / organization     := "com.example"
ThisBuild / organizationName := "example" 

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "Scala Seed Project",
    publishMavenStyle := true,
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test
  )

libraryDependencies += "com.example" % "scala-seed-project_2.12" % "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"


publishTo := {
  val local_repository = "file:/my_local_repo/"
  if (isSnapshot.value)
    Some("snapshots" at local_repository + "my_repo_snapshots")
  else
    Some("releases"  at local_repository + "my_repo_stsble")
}
```

Some details: I want to union all caches (sbt, boot, ivy, coursier) in subfolders of one folder (/cache/)
The first build is success but the following builds with error above

Comment: Can you show your `build.sbt` file?

Comment: Hello. I added my build.sbt in description

Comment: Can you upgrade to Scala 2.12.11 and try again?

Comment: It did not help. I use sbt 1.3.10 and as I understand sbt is download this version himself

Comment: I use user which not root. If I will remove sbt boot folder entirely it  will solve my problem. If I remove all .lock files only - it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

After a recent experience with this problem using IntelliJ, invalidating the cache and restarting seemed to have solved the problem.

IntelliJ Guide to clearing cache: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html

Screenshot of specific cache cleared: [image: Screenshot of IntelliJ Clear Cache Options with "Clear file system cache and Local History" selected]